# link_to called upon page refresh -- Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, session, link-to

I'm new to RoR and this is my first post on Stack Overflow!

I created the following function to start a game. `session[@translationsCount]` is set to 0 to render the 'welcome' partial, and upon pressing the "Start" link, [:@translationsCount] should be set to 1 to render another partial. However, when I refresh the page, [:@translationsCount] increases to 1. This issue only began after I included the .click function. Please help!

---

"_welcome.html.erb"

```
 <h2>WELCOME!</h2>

<h2>Translate from English to: </h2>

<%= collection_select(:language, :language_id, @langArr, :id, :language, {class: "input_standard", id: "languageList"}) %>



<%= link_to "Start", "#", id: "startButton" %>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var value = $('#languageList').val()
    console.log("Language selected is " + value)
    console.log("Translations count is " + "<%= session[:@translationsCount] %>")

    var clickFunction = '<%= session[:@translationsCount] %>';

    $('#startButton').click(function(){
        <% session[:@translationsCount] = 1 %>

        console.log("LANGUAGE SELECTED IS" + value)
        <% session[:@languageSelected] %> = value
        console.log("Translations count2 is" + "<%= session[:@translationsCount] %>")
        console.log("<%= session[:@languageSelected] %>")
    });


</script>
```

Comment: `<% session[:@languageSelected] %> = value` doesn't work like that. When the page is already rendered and displayed on the browser, it is already completely independent of your Rails code. I think it would be easier understood through this: while the page is displayed on the browser, right click on anything on the page, and click "Inspect", then you will notice that your Javascript code above is already "rendered" on the page and it does not contain any JS logic/code that will set the session value on click.